How to add multiple selected assets to scene?
I'm wondering, is it possible to batch add selected assets into scene somehow? Currently only the active asset appears in scene during drag'n'drop.

It can't be done from the asset manager at the moment, for mass linking/appending, use File > Append or File > Link
